# create a firewall exception using a batch file

Tags: batch-file, firewall

I am trying to make an automatic `LAN joiner` for a `LAN party` I am having but I need to know how to create a `firewall` exception for the `games.exe`?

The file location that need an exception is: `lanparty\exes\halo4.exe`

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about the windows firewall use:

```
Netsh Firewall
```

Type:

```
Netsh Firewall /?
```

From the Command prompt to get the list of parameters

If you're using another software firewall, you need to specify which one. 
If it's a hardware firewall you need to specify which one as well.

There really isn't enough information to answer this question accurately